# "dinosaurs to fly" vs "flying dinosaurs"

Tags: comparisons

I read a passage from an LSAT:

"It seems likely that the earliest dinosaurs to fly did so by gliding out of trees rather than, as some scientists think, by lifting off the ground from a running start. Animals gliding from trees are able to fly with very simple wings. Such wings represent evolutionary middle stages toward developing the large wings that we associate with flying dinosaurs."

Could someone explain and parse out this weird subject "the earliest dinosaurs to fly"? What's the usage here? Is it a reduced form?

I found this particularly bizarre when reading "flying dinosaur" at the end. It seems the test maker distinguishes between "flying dinosaur" and "dinosaur to fly".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a duplicate of [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/301216/dinosaurs-to-fly-vs-flying-dinosaurs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *the earliest dinosaurs to fly*

This is a noun phrase in which "to fly" is an infinitival relative clause modifying "dinosaurs".

Infinitival relatives characteristically have a modal meaning comparable to that expressed in finite relative clauses by "can" and "should". Your example is comparable to "the earliest dinosaurs who could fly".

Comment: What’s clear is that before there were dinosaurs that flew (or could fly) there were dinosaurs that could not do so. At lease that would be my conclusion.

Comment: What's really clear is that the construction is _earliest to fly_. _Dinosaurs_ is indeed the subject of _to fly_, but the construction doesn't require a noun phrase to modify. _The dinosaurs that were earliest to fly_ has the same sense; the infinitive doesn't really "modify" anything. That's different from _flying dinosaurs_, where _flying_ **does** modify _dinosaurs_, because it's an adjective.

Comment: "Earliest to fly" is not a constituent. This is a clear case of an infinitival relative clause modifying the head noun, "dinosaurs". The nominal is "earliest dinosaurs to fly", which contains "earliest" as modifier. Note that "earliest" could be replaced by the ordinal "first".